# WSO2 IS : Logging with username and password

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 Identity server. i have a use case, if i login with locally developed .net web application with username and password(provided by wso2is), wso2is should be able to authenticate these credential and if these credentials are valid then it will be able to navigate to dummy website or url for testing purpose.

Can you please let me know how to achieve this using wso2IS.

Thank you
Munna

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to authenticate a user from Identity Server. Easiest way is that you can call the admin service (SOAP service) for authentication (RemoteUserStoreManagerService/authenticate) [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-authenticate()).

Or you can create a OAuth application inside the IS and use resource owner grant type to pass the credentials and authenticate [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Try+Password+Grant).

Comment: Thank you for the details. I tried RemoteUserStoreManagerService/authenticate process and imported the wsdl file and tested the service.if i pass the admin username then authentication service returning response as true. if i pass the user which i created(ex:mmulla and credentials as admin),then service is returning false. Any idea how to validate it and also please let me know how this works. Also, can you please tell me how to expose this service as REST service to test authentication. my requirement is to generate authentication REST service and hook it up in front end application

Comment: Check whether you have given the login permission to that user. Currently admin services are only hosted as SOAP services (Other than few governance services). You can use OAuth password grant which somewhat similar to calling a REST service.

Comment: Thank you. I validated the permissions and granted all permissions. Still it is returning false. I am working on testing the OAuth password grant type. Can you please share rest url if you have any related to password grant type and reference url. I will configure in my front end application and tested out.

Comment: Hi, You can use the below link for your requirement. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Try+Request+Path+Authentication